# Extract/Alter/Delete data from copied sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Thanks guys. 
I need to copy & paste 2 sheets which have references to each other. I have found a way to group them and copy/paste both of them at the same time. However i have difficulties trying to  extract/change/delete values from each individual sheet. Or how do i even select each 1 of the 2 sheets.

Below is my code to group & copy/paste the 2 sheets.

```
Dim myArray As Variant
'select workbook
Workbooks("InsertTempSheets.xlsm").Activate

'group 2 sheets and make copies
myArray = Array("Working1", "Working2")
Sheets(myArray).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Any help is appreciated guys. Thanks alot.

Comment: I just remembered, I answered a similar question earlier and hence I deleted my answer.

Comment: This question or rather the code in it possibly solves one of my questions. As for you question, just `Set` the worksheets indindividually then work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a workbook with two worksheets, "Working1" and "Working2". I created a Sub containing your code (without

```
Workbooks("InsertTempSheets.xlsm").Activate
```

) and executed it. It works perfectly. Could you specify what "difficulties trying to extract/change/delete values from each individual sheet" did you find?

Any details, messages, errors will help.